# IntelliJ do not format blank lines

Tags: java, android-studio, intellij-idea

I would like to manage blank lines in my code but everytime I hit <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd> (format document), IntelliJ inserts and deletes blank lines however it sees fit.

For example, I would like to do this:

```java
package example;
import something1;
import something2;
import java.util.*;

class Example
{
    private void method1() {}
    private void method2() {}

    private void method3() {}
    private void method4() {}
}
```

Basically I want no extra blank lines between individual imports and I want to split methods into groups. However IntelliJ formats code above as such:

```java
package example;
import something1;
import something2;

import java.util.*;

class Example
{
    private void method1() {}
    private void method2() {}
    private void method3() {}
    private void method4() {}
}
```

I tried changing values in **File** → **Settings** → **Editor** → **Code Style** → **Java** → **Blank Lines**, however I don't see an option to stop IntelliJ from managing blank lines at all.

I also hope that similar can be done for Android Studio because it is based on the IntelliJ platform.

Comment: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/topics

Comment: @DavidCullen How is that supposed to help? Should I just copy my question there? As per my understanding on StackOverflow there are more people who use IntelliJ than on the official forums so the chances are I won't get an answer from IntelliJ forums.

Comment: [https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-23938?_ga=2.82224661.2048375040.1602334903-888281352.1598541986](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-23938?_ga=2.82224661.2048375040.1602334903-888281352.1598541986)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the behaviour shown above (with IDEA 2020.3 EAP, probably works with other versions):

Editor, Code Style, Java, Imports, Import Layout: remove the blank lines in the table.

Editor, Code Style, Java, Blank Lines: Keep maximum, In declarations: 1

Editor, Code Style, Java, Blank Lines: Minimum blank lines, Around method: 0